# Z3 Solver timing out with abstract ring

Tags: z3

I am trying to define an abstract semiring with the Z3 solver, however anytime that I attempt to perform any operation using the ring the solver seemingly runs forever.

Currently I have the following Z3 smt code:

```
; declare the ring elements
(declare-sort R)

(declare-fun add (R R) R)
(declare-fun mul (R R) R)

(declare-fun one () R)
(declare-fun zero () R)

; the add properties
(assert (forall ((a R)) (= (add a zero) a)))
(assert (forall ((a R) (b R)) (= (add a b) (add b a))))
(assert (forall ((a R) (b R) (c R)) (= (add (add a b) c) (add a (add b c)))))

; the multiply properties
(assert (forall ((a R)) (= (mul a one) a)))
(assert (forall ((a R)) (= (mul a zero) zero)))
(assert (forall ((a R) (b R)) (= (mul a b) (mul b a))))
(assert (forall ((a R) (b R) (c R)) (= (mul (mul a b) c) (mul a (mul b c)))))

; distributive
(assert (forall ((a R) (b R) (c R)) (= (mul a (add b c)) (add (mul a b) (mul a c)))))

; different elements
(assert (distinct zero one))

; Either of the following blocks on their own cause the solver to run seemingly forever
(declare-fun fubar () R)
(assert (= fubar (mul fubar one)))

(assert (= zero (mul zero one)))



(set-option :timeout 100000)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: As a first step, add explicit triggers to your quantifiers to reduce the likelihood of causing matching loops. Check the quantifier statistics or use the Axiom Profiler (https://bitbucket.org/viperproject/axiom-profiler) to see if matching loops could explain the poor performance you observe.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt Z3 is suitable for these sorts of problems, due to heavy use of quantifiers. Finite model finding and e-matching isn't easy. Perhaps good old theorem proving might be a better choice here, or at least being very explicit about cardinalities so quantification can be removed. (Which will only work reasonably for small domains, admittedly.)